# MySql If, Left Join Trouble

Tags: mysql

Here is my query

```
select 
    p.products_id, p.products_type, p.master_categories_id, p.manufacturers_id, 
    p.products_price, p.products_tax_class_id, p.products_priced_by_attribute, 
    pd.products_description, pd.products_special_data, IF(s.status = 1, 
    s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) as specials_new_products_price,
    IF(p.products_priced_by_attribute = 1, pa.options_values_price, 
        IF(s.status = 1, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) 
    ) as final_price, 
    p.product_is_call, p.product_is_always_free_shipping, p.products_qty_box_status 
from products p 
left join specials s on p.products_id = s.products_id 
left join products_attributes pa on p.products_id = pa.products_id, 
products_description pd, 
manufacturers m, 
products_to_categories p2c 
where p.products_status = 1 
    and p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id 
    and p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
    and pd.products_id = p2c.products_id 
    and p.products_price >= 221 
    and p.products_price <= 815 
    and pd.language_id = '1' 
    and p2c.categories_id = '630'
```

structure of products table:

```
products_id     products_type   products_quantity   products_model  products_image  products_price  products_virtual    products_date_added     products_last_modified  products_date_available     products_weight     products_status     products_tax_class_id   manufacturers_id    products_ordered    products_quantity_order_min     products_quantity_order_units   products_priced_by_attribute    product_is_free     product_is_call     products_quantity_mixed     product_is_always_free_shipping     products_qty_box_status     products_quantity_order_max     products_sort_order     products_discount_type  products_discount_type_from     products_price_sorter   master_categories_id    products_mixed_discount_quantity    metatags_title_status   metatags_products_name_status   metatags_model_status   metatags_price_status   metatags_title_tagline_status   qbi_imported    attributePosition   supplier    flat_rate_shipable  products_upc    products_condition
```

structure of products_attributes table:

```
products_attributes_id  products_id     options_id  options_values_id   options_values_price    price_prefix    products_options_sort_order     product_attribute_is_free   products_attributes_weight  products_attributes_weight_prefix   attributes_display_only     attributes_default  attributes_discounted   attributes_image    attributes_price_base_included  attributes_price_onetime    attributes_price_factor     attributes_price_factor_offset  attributes_price_factor_onetime     attributes_price_factor_onetime_offset  attributes_qty_prices   attributes_qty_prices_onetime   attributes_price_words  attributes_price_words_free     attributes_price_letters    attributes_price_letters_free   attributes_required     minimum_quantity
```

The issue is that I have a result of four products and there should be five. The one that's missing is the one who's p.products_priced_by_attribute does equal 1. I can't tell if it's not being returned because there are actually 3 rows for it in the pov table and it needs a limit of 1 or if I'm just not properly relating to the pov table at all.

Comment: What's the problem? What do you expect to happen vs what is actually happening?

Comment: Sorry about that! Well I have a result of four products and there should be five. The one that's missing is the one who's p.products_priced_by_attribute does equal 1. I can't tell if it's not being returned because there are actually 3 rows for it in the pov table and it needs a limit of 1 or if I'm just not properly relating to the pov table at all.

Comment: Can we get rid of all the php for now?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's going on from your code alone, maybe post the database structure along with some sample data and the results you're getting vs what you're expecting to get.

Comment: Also, don't mix implcit and explicit JOIN styles. In fact, don't use implicit (comma-) join syntax at all.

Comment: Add your question to question, please

Comment: your on statement is using comma's instead of `OR` or `AND` criteria. `ON p.products_id = pa.products_id,
  products_description pd,
  manufacturers m,
  products_to_categories p2c` shouldn't be this way or you are mixing join types as previously stated  additionally the where clause criteria seems to be potentially negating the left join.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I'd start with the following, and then frame my question around that...

```
SELECT p.products_id
     , p.products_type
     , p.master_categories_id
     , p.manufacturers_id
     , p.products_price
     , p.products_tax_class_id
     , p.products_priced_by_attribute
     , pd.products_description
     , pd.products_special_data
     , pa.options_id
     , pa.options_values_price
     , IF(s.status = 1, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) specials_new_products_price
     , IF(p.products_priced_by_attribute = 1, pa.options_values_price, IF(s.status = 1, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price)) final_price
     , p.product_is_call
     , p.product_is_always_free_shipping
     , p.products_qty_box_status
  FROM products p 
  LEFT
  JOIN specials s
    ON s.products_id = p.products_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN products_attributes pa 
    ON pa.products_id = p.products_id 
  JOIN products_to_categories p2c
    ON p2c.products_id = p.products_id 
  JOIN products_description pd
    ON pd.products_id = p2c.products_id
  JOIN manufactureres m
    ON m.manufacturers_id = p.manufacturers_id 
 WHERE p.products_status = 1
   AND pd.language_id = $_SESSION['languages_id']
   AND p2c.categories_id = $current_category_id;
```